# Lazy Loading components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have seen two ways to lazy load components in angular :

1. Using routes (using loadchildern)
2. Using ViewContainerRef and ComponentFactoryResolver

What is the difference between both techniques?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know,

[loadChildren](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-basics) is used to lazy load the modules but not the components. It means that you are loading all the components contained in the module into the browser. This will be helpful to lazy load feature modules

To lazy load components (feature of Angular 9), we need ComponentFactoryResolver.

[ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) is also required to load any components dynamically (existing feature in all the Angular2+ versions)

Yes of course we need [ViewContanierRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) which acts as the placeholder to add new component at particular spot in the DOM

P.S: I am not adding example codes just to be within the limits of the question

Comment: thank you, i was actually confused between lazy loading components and modules. its clear now.